# Objective C xpath get multiple tags value

Tags: objective-c, xpath

I have the following html structure:

```
<img src="http://mfc.mk.ua/images/team-summer-2014/fedorchuk.jpg.pagespeed.ce.DW4HZMlyDH.jpg" alt="" align="left" class="border"/>
<p class="name">ФЕДОРЧУК Олег</p>
<p class="job">Главный тренер</p>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<img src="http://mfc.mk.ua/images/team-summer-2014/ponomarenko.jpg.pagespeed.ce.UeToKr_U19.jpg" alt="" align="left" class="border"/>
<p class="name">ПОНОМАРЕНКО Владимир</p>
<p class="job">Тренер</p>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<img src="http://mfc.mk.ua/images/team-summer-2014/stavka.jpg.pagespeed.ce.G_ytrInjvR.jpg" alt="" align="left" class="border"/>
<p class="name">СТАВКА Анатолий</p>
<p class="job">Тренер</p>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<img src="http://mfc.mk.ua/images/team-summer-2014/smagin.jpg.pagespeed.ce.NwCyiMxVvh.jpg" alt="" align="left" class="border"/>
<p class="name">СМАГИН Юрий</p>
<p class="job">Тренер-селекционер</p>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<img src="http://mfc.mk.ua/images/team-summer-2014/tokarskiy.jpg.pagespeed.ce.RzOJcRrYEB.jpg" alt="" align="left" class="border"/>
<p class="name">ТОКАРСКИЙ Андрей</p>
<p class="job">Администратор</p>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<img src="http://mfc.mk.ua/images/team-summer-2014/lazutin.jpg.pagespeed.ce.YBG6DtzsRG.jpg" alt="" align="left" class="border"/>
<p class="name">ЛАЗУТИН Алексей</p>
<p class="job">Врач</p>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<img src="http://mfc.mk.ua/images/team-summer-2014/logush.jpg.pagespeed.ce.Hp2-pqey6s.jpg" alt="" align="left" class="border"/>
<p class="name">ЛОГУШ Иван</p>
<p class="job">Массажист</p>
```

I want to select multilple tags value such as name,job and image url. Im using this code to get these values

```
    NSString *coachesXpathQueryString = @"//p[@class='name']";

    NSArray *coachesNodes = [coachesParser searchWithXPathQuery: coachesXpathQueryString];

    NSMutableArray *newCoach = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 0];

    for (TFHppleElement *element in coachesNodes)
    {
        Coach *coach = [[Coach alloc] init];

        [newCoach addObject: coach];

        coach.name = [element content];

        _coaches = newCoach;

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

But im get only name, i dont want to create new xpathString for other values. I want use one. Is is possible? can you help me,thanks.

**So the question, can I fetch another element' content by one time `searchWithXPathQuery` ?**

Comment: You could project a single concatenated string per name + job pair from xpath, but then you would need to split this again in your code?

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: I want to create cell with image, name and job for each coach

Comment: If you have a XPath2 capable parser, you can project a delimited concatenation of your tuples, e.g. by `//p[@class='name']/concat(./text(), '|', following-sibling::p[@class='job']/text())`

Comment: Something like this:
https://pp.vk.me/c621517/v621517851/acd4/HhkCpGJcgpw.jpg

Comment: I'm behind a corporate firewall - can't access that picture :(

Comment: Showing a picture of rendered HTML is really not useful. Always describe results as _code_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a XPath2 capable parser, you can project a delimited concatenation of your tuples, e.g. by

```
//p[@class='name']/concat(./text(), '|', following-sibling::p[@class='job']/text())
```